# Cross comparison of 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a little trouble cross comparing two arrays.  I have a function which builds up an array of groups for me.  I then call it

```
$groups = getGroups();
```

The above call will output something like the following

```
array(144) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["GroupName"]=>
    string(4) "Group One"
    ["GroupEmail"]=>
    string(25) "groupOne@someEmail.com"
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["GroupMember"]=>
      string(13) "John Doe"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["GroupMember"]=>
      string(11) "Jane Murray"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["GroupMember"]=>
      string(10) "Julie Wise"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I then make another call to get some user data by doing

```
$users = getUsers();
```

The output of this array is something like this

```
array(66) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["UserName"]=>
    string(14) "John Doe"
    ["email"]=>
    string(27) "johnd@someEmail.com"
  }
  ...
}
```

What I am trying to do now is bind the 2 arrays.  My aim is to get something like the following outputted

```
Group One:  groupOne@someEmail.com, johnd@someEmail.com, janeMurray@someEmail.com, julieWise@someEmail.com
```

So the above is

```
GroupName:  GroupEmail, GroupMember->email
```

So I need to get the groups GroupMember, cross check this with the UserName held within my users array, in order to get their email.

Would something like this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on your array. Didn't understand exactly what you want but hope i guessed it.

```
foreach($groups as $groupKey=>$groupData)
{
    if(is_array($groupData))
    {
        foreach($groupData as $memberKey=>$memberData)
        {
            $res = array_search($memberData['GroupMember'],array_column($users, 'UserName'));
            if($res !== false) {
                $groups[$groupKey][$memberKey]['email'] = $users[$res]['email'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will have as output:

```
 array(3) {
  ["GroupName"]=>
  string(9) "Group One"
  ["GroupEmail"]=>
  string(22) "groupOne@someEmail.com"
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["GroupMember"]=>
      string(8) "John Doe"
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "johnd@someEmail.com"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["GroupMember"]=>
      string(10) "Julie Wise"
      ["email"]=>
      string(19) "julie@someEmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.
Best regards,

M.I.

Comment: Made a few small changes but this helped a lot.  Thanks